# How do we setup integrated authentication using SQL Server for Tridion Database

Tags: sites-9.5, sql-server

We are upgrading from 8.5 to 9.5 and would like to enable integrated database authentication. Please share more details if possible.

Comment: Which database are you talking about? The content manager database, the content delivery database or any of the other databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the tridion documentation [sdl document](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-975723FD-3A94-40F6-BBC7-82571A851488) and refer to the below links
[enable integrated authentication](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012316)  for more details and also refer to the document which shows the steps on how to enable integrated database authentication refer to the document [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/servlet/fileField?retURL=%2Fapex%2Fcommunityknowledge%3FarticleName%3D000012316&entityId=ka54X000000oNTVQA2&field=Attachment1__Body__s)